# The dual space is isomorphic to the space of all absolutely summable sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I ran across following statement. I am not sure why it is true.

Let $c_0$ be a space of sequences $x=(x_1, \cdots, x_n, \cdots)$ converging to $0$ with the norm $\|x\|=\sup_n|x_n|$. Then the dual space is isomorphic to the space of all absolutely summable sequences $f=(f_1, \cdots, f_n, \cdots)$ with the norm $\|f\|=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|f_n|.$

Comment: Have you tried checking standard functional analysis textbooks? It's almost certainly possible to find a proof of this in them. You could also have tried searching on this site for "dual space of c_0" which would have yielded results. Try doing that first and if you struggle to understand those sources, ask a question about the particular bit you're struggling with.

Comment: You might want to consider the map $x\cdot f \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_nf_n$, which must converge since its tail is majorized by $f$.